# How do I stop a java java.util.Timer()

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a function that when I click a button it starts a thread and what I want it to do is when I click another button it will stop the thread. The thread timer that I am using looks like this.

```
new java.util.Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Blah Blah Blah       
                }
            }, 20, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // call the method cancel to stop it
    java.util.Timer time = new java.util.Timer();

    time.scheduleAtFixedRate(new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Blah Blah Blah       
            }
        }, 20, 5000);

    time.cancel();
```

Comment: this worked just the way I wanted it to, but now if i click start again it says the timer already cancelled.

Comment: To get around this i just create a new timer every time I click the start button.

Comment: Or you can call the method purge() on the object time.

Comment: Thank you I will try that as well to see what works better for what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need a Timer for this task? Timers are meant for scheduling thread execution in the future or at specific intervals.

Based on your task description, all you need to do is listen for the button presses, and start/stop the thread when triggered.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention I am sending a socket to a raspberry pi and waiting for a response while I have the start button activated